# Does setting source-map as devtool for webpack increase the build size in production?

Tags: webpack, build, source-maps

In the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) is stated that `devtool` set as `source-map` is one of the options recommended for production environments.

In the project the build folder size generated without setting a devtool for webpack is 2.9 MB and with the `source-map` option de build size increases up to 7.1 MB

It seems that this could have a clear impact on the client side since it would have to retrieve a larger build, or am I missing something?

Comment: 'You should configure your server to disallow access to the Source Map file for normal users!' -- have you read this?

Comment: I think I understand now, the `.map` generated files are not needed for the user and could be protected under a VPN only accessible for the development team. The users only download the `.map` files when developer tools are open so they are not affected by an increase in size when using the `devtool` option with the `source-map` value. Please publish your comment as the response so I can mark it as valid :)